# HTML PHP Contact Form - Submit Button Not Working? Or PHP Issue?

Tags: php, html

Hope you can help, I am trying to knock up a contact form for my website which is HTML, styled with CSS and the email sent with PHP.

```
<form class="form" action="webform.php" method="post">
    <h1>Contact Form:</h1>
    <label>
    <span>Your Name:</span><input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
    </label>

    <label>
    <span>Email Address:</span><input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
    </label>

    <label>
    <span>Subject:</span><input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" />
    </label>

    <label>
    <span>Message</span><textarea id="feedback" name="feedback"></textarea>
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Submit Form" />
    </label>
</form>
```

Anyone help me out, can provide the link to my site if necessary.

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Change your button **type="submit"**

Comment: Where is your submit button?it seems like button

Answer (score 3):

You should use submit as the button type

```
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v55zT/2/)

Answer (score 1):

[**See updated FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v55zT/1/)

Have you tried changing:

`<input id="button" type="button" value="Submit Form" />`

to:

`<input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit Form" />`

Alternatively, you can use:

`<button id="button" >Submit Form</button>`

As you have it now, `input type='button'` is not a valid element for form submission. For valid form elements, [MDN have a great article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/The_native_form_widgets?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML/Forms/The_native_form_widgets)- see the sections **input** and **buttons**

Answer (score 0):

Change **type="button"** to **type="submit"**

```
<form class="form" action="webform.php" method="post">
    <h1>Contact Form:</h1>
    <label>
    <span>Your Name:</span><input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
    </label>

    <label>
    <span>Email Address:</span><input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
    </label>

    <label>
    <span>Subject:</span><input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" />
    </label>

    <label>
    <span>Message</span><textarea id="feedback" name="feedback"></textarea>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: what difference does your answer have to the answers given above?

Comment: Yep. Am using mobile internet with dial up connection.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I agree with the suggested solutions re: `type="submit`.

But I arrived here due to having my buttons stop working all of a sudden, though a Select submit was still working. And it was due to a tiny bug in some Javascript that was killing the submission.

Just something else to check.

Answer (score -1):

try this html form

```
<form class="form" action="webform.php" method="post">
    <h1>Contact Form:</h1>
    <label>
    <span>Your Name:</span><input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
    </label>

    <label>
    <span>Email Address:</span><input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
    </label>

    <label>
    <span>Subject:</span><input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" />
    </label>

    <label>
    <span>Message</span><textarea id="feedback" name="feedback"></textarea>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
    </label> </form>
```